# How to use math.log10 function on whole pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to take the logarithm of every value in a pandas dataframe. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
#Reading data from excel and rounding values on 2 decimal places
import math
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("DataSet.xls").round(2)
log_data= math.log10(data)
```

It gives me this error:

> TypeError: must be real number, not DataFrame

Do you have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the numpy version, not math

```
import numpy as np

np.log10(df)
```

Comment: Thanks my friend!!!
Do you have any idea what to do if some values in pandas dataframe are 0?
Then, I cant use log function

Comment: (Note that if numpy has no equivalent of the function you want, you can also use `np.vectorize(function)` to turn any scalar function into a vector function.)

Comment: @Aleksandar At that point, you'll have to decide what you want to happen to the zeros. Numpy can handle whatever you choose without difficulty.

Comment: @ChristophBurschka: But if you do that, it's going to be way slower than a "natively" vectorized function, as well as producing [silently wrong results](https://ideone.com/sTrs4l) if you aren't careful about having consistent output dtypes.

Answer (score 12):

From what it seems `math.log10` cannot handle neither pandas dataframes nor ndarrays.

So one option would be to go with numpy, which also includes a function to compute the base 10 logarithm, `np.log10`, and reconstruct the dataframe as pointed out in other solutions.

Or if you want to go with `math.log10`, and the same would apply to other functions that cannot be directly vectorized, you can use [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to apply `math.log10` to the dataframe elementwise. Do note however that this solution will be slower than a vectorized approach using `np.log10`.

---

**Use case**

Here's an example of how this could be done using `DataFrame.applymap`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,(6,6)), columns=list('abcdef'))

print(df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  3  4  1  1  2  1
1  4  4  4  3  4  1
2  4  3  3  1  4  1
3  3  4  1  3  1  1
4  1  2  3  4  2  1
5  1  3  3  1  4  3

df.applymap(math.log10)

      a         b         c         d        e         f
0  0.477121  0.602060  0.000000  0.000000  0.30103  0.000000
1  0.602060  0.602060  0.602060  0.477121  0.60206  0.000000
2  0.602060  0.477121  0.477121  0.000000  0.60206  0.000000
3  0.477121  0.602060  0.000000  0.477121  0.00000  0.000000
4  0.000000  0.301030  0.477121  0.602060  0.30103  0.000000
5  0.000000  0.477121  0.477121  0.000000  0.60206  0.477121
```

---

For the `numpy` solution, you could take the `np.log10` of the dataframe, and reconstruct it as:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.log10(data), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use the `applymap` method to apply `math.log10` on the whole dataframe, here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).

You can test it:

```
df.applymap(math.log10)
```